# Stability of Chemical Reactions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry, stability, complex-systems

Given the following reactions:

$$A + X \xrightarrow{k_{1}} 2 X$$

$$Y + X \xrightarrow{k_{2}} 2 Y$$

$$Y \xrightarrow{k_{3}} B$$

I was able to write the following rate equations for the concentrations:

$$\partial_{t}C_{X} =  k_{1} C_{A}^{0} - k_{2}C_{X}C_{Y} + D_{1} \nabla^2_{r} C_{X}$$

$$\partial_{t}C_{X} =  k_{2}C_{X}C_{Y} - k_{3}C_{Y} + D_{2} \nabla^2_{r} C_{Y}$$

For a similar example, in "A Modern Course in Statistical Physics" by Linda E. Reichl they redefine this variables to simplify the expression.

[image]

However I can't do the same for my expressions, is there anything I'm missing?

The redefinition of variables is quite useful, it makes our stability analysis much more simpler.

Comment: What is $\nabla^2_r$ here?

Comment: It’s not clear to me what “I can’t do the same” means. Why can’t you define some variables? What exactly is it that you’re seeking to achieve? A certain form of equations?

Comment: @RogerVadim We are allowing to the possibility of diffusion, D1 and D2 are the coefficients of diffusion

Comment: @Chemomechanics I can't "see" the change of variables I have to introduce to simplify each equation as done in Reichel's book

Yes, I'm trying to achieve a simplified version of the equations above to be able to analyse the stability

Comment: @RogerVadim Its the Laplacian with respect to position $\nabla^2_r := \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}  + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2} $, we are considering that these molar densities $C_i$ vary in space

Comment: Maybe this: Divide the first equation by $k_1$ and the second by $k_3$. From that try to find rescaled variables in similar fashion as the source you cited

Comment: @miniplanck That doesn’t really answer the question. Here’s an example of a specific goal: “I need at least one *single term* on the right side of at least one of the equations (as in $A$ of the other example).”

Comment: Should your second rate equation be for $\partial_t C_Y$ rather than $\partial_t C_X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to eliminate most of the leading coefficients (except for the diffusion terms), then the way to systematically do this would be to define your new variables in terms of your old ones, each one multiplied by an undetermined scaling factor:
$$
\tilde{t} = \alpha t \quad A^0 = \beta_A C_A^0 \quad X = \beta_X C_X \quad Y = \beta_Y C_Y \quad \tilde{D}_1 = \gamma_1 D_1 \quad \tilde{D}_2 = \gamma_2 D_2
$$
Rewrite your rate equations in terms of these new variables,  multiply both sides of each equation by an appropriate constant so that the coefficient of some term (the $\partial C_i/\partial \tilde{t}$ terms, for example) is 1.  Each of the remaining terms will then have a coefficient in terms of the rescaling factors $\{ \alpha, \beta_A, \beta_X, \beta_Y, \gamma_1, \gamma_2\}$, the reaction rates, and the diffusion constants. The requirement that each of these coefficients is equal to 1 will impose an equation relating these quantities to each other, which you can then solve for the rescaling factors.

For example, the first equation, under these rescalings, becomes
\begin{align*}
\frac{\alpha}{\beta_X} \partial_\tilde{t} X &= \frac{k_1}{\beta_A} A^0 - \frac{k_2}{\beta_X \beta_Y} XY + \frac{1}{\gamma_1 \beta_X} \tilde{D}_1 \nabla^2 X \\
\partial_\tilde{t} X &= \frac{k_1 \beta_X}{\beta_A \alpha} A^0 - \frac{k_2}{\alpha \beta_Y} XY + \frac{1}{\gamma_1 \alpha} \tilde{D}_1 \nabla^2 X \\
\end{align*}
which implies that we want $k_1 \beta_x/\beta_A \alpha = 1$, $k_2/\beta_Y \alpha = 1$, and $\gamma_1 \alpha = 1$.  Applying this same procedure to the second rate equation will give three more equations, which you can then solve for $\{ \alpha, \beta_A, \beta_X, \beta_Y, \gamma_1, \gamma_2\}$.

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for. Thank you kindly!